# Did Diablo Cody intentionally have Juno use the mashed-up phrase, "Thundercats are go!"?

Tags: dialogue, juno

In the birth scene of *[Juno](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0467406/)*, the titular character yells, *"Thundercats are go!"*, which is obviously a mashup of the *"Thundercats, ho!"* and *"Thunderbirds are go!"* declarations from the *[Thundercats](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088631/)* cartoon and the unrelated *[Thunderbirds](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057790/)* marionette show, respectively.

Was this a deliberate mashup by the writer, a production mishap, or a misread from actor Ellen (now Elliot) Page?  Was this incorrect phrase used intentionally, possibly reflecting a confused state of mind, or completely unintentionally?

Ultimately, was the line supposed to be the inaccurate phrase *"Thundercats are go!"*, or one of the two correct phrases?  Did someone "get it wrong" unintentionally or deliberately?

Comment: Short of asking Diablo Cody or Ellen Page, I'm not sure how we could answer this. :(

Comment: @Catija Well, at least we don't have to ask them if others did already.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson A quick google search containing the phrase doesn't turn up any interviews including this topic.

Comment: From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thundercats%20are%20go): > Thundercats was an old TV show that was amazing. The Thundercats used
> to shout Thundercats go when they left any place they are at.
> > Alex: Dude I'm so glad you found booze Jimmy: Shit the coppers are
> coming! Thundercats Are GOOOOO!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, [the script](https://web.archive.org/web/20140227233108/https://finearts.uvic.ca/writing/websites/writ218/screenplays/award_winning/Juno.html) (scene 105a) shows Juno says: "Thundercats are go!", so Elliot Page read his line correctly. It was as written, so you'd need to ask Diablo Cody why it was mashed up.

Comment: Let's take the questions asked one at a time: did production intentionally... yes, Was it a deliberate mashup by the writer? yes. A production mishap, no, it was scripted. Was it a misread by Ms. Page? Nope.The **only** question, among (I count 5) all the questions asked is the last. And half of that is answered, yes, it was used intentionally.

Comment: I don't know that you could say it's a *deliberate* mashup... it's perfectly possible that Cody just got it wrong in her script... people misquote stuff (even iconic stuff) from their youth simply because they remember it incorrectly.

Comment: So, do we know if Cody **meant** to use Thunderbirds? No, we don't. However, as the rest of the script uses sly witticisms like that (doodle can't be un-did), I would not presume to suggest she messed up.

Comment: It is good to know that it was in the script that way, but I would prefer to know whether the script writer "got it wrong" intentionally.  I suspect there must be an interview somewhere where someone asked Diablo Cody this question.

Comment: An anonymous user submitted an edit suggestion replacing Ellen with Elliot and her with his. The edit was rejected. After thinking about this, I've decided to make the change. The actor is now known as Elliot and identifies as male, so the change is a correct one. Please note, however, that when this film was made, Elliot was Ellen and (identified as) female at that time.